# cannot open database "susdb" required by the login. the logic failed login failed for user 'nt authority\network service'

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, powershell

i am trying to run a PowerShell script to get patching upgrade details from wsus server but i am getting the following error.

cannot open database "susdb" required by the login. the logic failed login failed for user 'nt authority\network service'

Below are the command we are hitting
$wsusConfig = Get-WsusServer -Name "Server_IP" -PortNumber 8530

the script was running successfully from past few days but it is giving me error now.

[image]

we tried below things.

1. we checked wsus services. all dependencies of wsus services were running but wsus service was getting stopped.
2. event logs, systems logs.
3. account lockouts.

Comment: See if [this blog post](https://hodzice.wordpress.com/2016/05/20/sccm-and-wsus-cannot-open-database-susdb/) helps.